# vbulletin membership list header change

Tags: vbulletin

I have a vbulletin website. I need to change the label "Posts" to "Forums". Just the label, not the functionality. If you need to see an example please visit this link, http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/memberlist.php . Here you can see "post" in the table header. I need to change that. It may be very simple, but i have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the *memberlist* template i think your looking for

< vb:if condition="$show['searchcol']">< th>< span class="blocksubhead">{vb:rawphrase find_posts_user}

you want to change the {vb:rawphrase find_posts_user} to Forums

edit: sorry about the spaces in the vb code. it was trying to render it as HTML here.